# Неправильное отображение шрифта в <span> на iPhone

Tags: html, css, css3

Проблема в том, что на iPhone некорректно отображается размер шрифта одного конкретного тега, хотя ему явно задан размер.
На других мобильных устройствах всё нормально.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    span {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="site-header-top-phone">
    <span>+7 (495) 797-56-65</span>
</div>
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @decyrus, спасибо большое. Все заработало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это вызвано тем, что содержимое тега является номером телефона. Вы можете отключить обнаружение телефонов с помощью:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Но так как Safari добавляет префикс `tel` для обнаруженных телефонов, то можно переопределить стиль: `a[href^=tel] { /*your style*/ }`, сохранив функциональность по набору номера.